# Can a JProgressBar show that a thread is alive?

Tags: java, multithreading, jprogressbar

I'm trying to learn about threads and JProgressBar.

I have a class that implements `Runnable`.  Let's say that the `run()` just sleeps for 20 seconds and displays "Hello World".

Is it possible to create a JProgressBar that updates for as long as the thread is active?

If I had an `int incrementer`, could I do something like this (it doesn't work, obviously, but is there something along these lines?):

```
while (Thread.isAlive()) {
    incrementer++;

    progress.setValue(incrementer);
    Rectangle progressRect = progress.getBounds();
    progressRect.x = 0;
    progressRect.y = 0;
    progress.paintImmediately( progressRect ); 
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to update the progress bar from the context of the thread, other wise you'll be blocking the a Event Dispatching Thread (EDT). This will mean you will need to synchronise the update with the EDT using something SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

Take a closer look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

You could also take a look at the [indeterminate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate%28boolean%29) state of the progress bar, which can be used to indicate work in progress when you don't know how much work needs to be done

You could also use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) which progress support via it's `PropertyChange` support

Comment: So if I run it with `invokeLater(this)` what integer am I using to make the progress bar progress?  Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: You would need to define a new instance of `Runnable` which was capable of updating the progress bar, to this end you would probably need to create a custom class which implements `Runnable` and took a `int` value via the constructor, then, in it's `run` method, update the progress bar accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for everything.  I'm figuring all this out as I go.  Using a SwingWorker now and I'm about to ask what I hope is a better question.